# R - aggregate data for 1 column by another column, based on statistices on a 3rd column

Tags: r, aggregate

Let's say I have an R data frame with 3 columns **A**, **B** and **C** , Where **A** values are not all distinct.

How do I do I get for all values of A, the value of C for which B is minimum (for that value of A) ?
Something like in pseudo SQL code : `SELECT C WHERE B = MIN(B) GROUPBY A` ?

I have looked at the `aggregate()` function but I am not sure it can get it done.

`aggregate(B ~ A, data = mydataframe, min)` only gives me the min of B for each A, but then I do not know how to get the corresponding C value.

Is there a way to subset the data frame with the result of this aggregation in order to get the C values, and / or can it be done in only one call of `aggregate()` ?

Thanks

An example of what I would like to get:

input:

```
A   B   C
1   0   1
1   2   2
1   1   3
1   1   4
2   1   1
2   2   2
2   0   3
2   3   4
```

output:

```
1
3
```

1 is the valueof C corresponding to the minimum of B (0) for A = 1

3 is the value of C corresponding to the minimum of B (0) for A = 2

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mydataframe)

DT[ , C[which.min(B)], by = "A"]
#    A V1
# 1: 1  1
# 2: 2  3
```

Or `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydataframe %.%
  group_by(A) %.%
  summarise(res = C[which.min(B)])
#   A res
# 1 2   3
# 2 1   1
```

Or the base function `by`:

```
by(mydataframe, mydataframe$A, function(x) x$C[which.min(x$B)])
# mydataframe$A: 1
# [1] 1
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# mydataframe$A: 2
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks, the data.table solution is pretty nice (and fast)! For my understanding, I was trying to get aggregate to work based on your solution, do you have any idea why the following does not work ? : aggregate(cbind(B,C) ~ A, data = mydataframe, function(x,y) y[which.min(x)])

Comment: @JeanpierreNenuphar This command doesn't work since the function in `aggregate` is applied to all columns *seperately*.

Comment: Does anyone know why the data.tables version doesn't work in a package/how to get the data.tables one to work in a package?

Answer (score 4):

**1)** SQLite guarantees that when you use `min` or `max` the other column variables will come from the same row so we get a particularly simple solution:

```
library(sqldf)

# one minimum per group
sqldf("select A, min(B) B, C from DF group by A")
```

If there can be duplicated minima and we want all of them then this select using a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) works:

```
# all minima per group
sqldf("select * from DF x 
      where x.b = (select min(y.b) from DF y where y.a = x.a)")
```

**2)** Using `ave` in the base of R we can do this:

```
# one minimum per group
subset(DF, !! ave(B, A, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) == which.min(x)))

# all minima per group
subset(DF, !! ave(B, A, FUN = function(x) x == min(x)))
```

**3)** If you do want to use `aggregate` then do it like this:

```
# one minimum per group
sq <- 1:nrow(DF)
DF[aggregate(sq ~ A, DF, function(ix) ix[which.min(DF$B[ix])])$sq, ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the table on columns A and B:

```
d<-structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), B = c(0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L), C = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
d2<-d[order(d$A, d$B),]
```

The data frame d2 should appear as follows:

```
  A B C
1 1 0 1
3 1 1 3
4 1 1 4
2 1 2 2
7 2 0 3
5 2 1 1
6 2 2 2
8 2 3 4
```

Since in the sorted data frame the values of B are in ascending order inside of every value of A, the first row of each different A value is the one that corresponds to the minimum of B.

Then, using the function `duplicated()` and the usual subscript, remove all the lines that are not duplicated in A, and return only the values from C (the third column):

```
d2[!duplicated(d2$A),3]
[1] 1 3
```